# Linux Bitlocker equivalent

Tags: linux, disk-encryption

Bitlocker is a harddrive encryption data protection tool which comes with Windows Vista Ultimate and 7. Does anyone know an equivalent for Linux distros like Fedora and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/)

> Main Features:
>
> - Creates a virtual encrypted disk within a file and mounts it as a real
>     disk.
> - Encrypts an entire partition or storage device such as USB flash drive
>     or hard drive.
> - Encrypts a partition or drive where Windows is installed (pre-boot
>     authentication).
> - Encryption is automatic, real-time (on-the-fly) and transparent.
> - Parallelization and pipelining allow data to be read and written as
>     fast as if the drive was not
>     encrypted.
> - Encryption can be hardware-accelerated on modern
>     processors.
> - Provides plausible deniability, in case an adversary forces you to reveal
>     the password:
> - Hidden volume (steganography) and hidden operating system.

**UPDATE 8/4/2014:**

With TrueCrypt shutting down, there are a few other options out there with [AES Crypt](http://www.aescrypt.com/linux_aes_crypt.html) leading the pack.

> AES Crypt is the perfect tool for anyone who carries sensitive
>   information with them while traveling, uploads sensitive files to
>   servers on the Internet, or wishes to protect sensitive information
>   from being stolen from the home or office. AES Crypt is also the
>   perfect solution for those who wish to backup information and store
>   that data at a bank, in a cloud-based storage service, and any place
>   where sensitive files might be accessible by someone else.

Comment: Is there any module that comes along with the distribution?

Comment: @ryan TomMD Noted the specifics about the distros however if you are looking to get TrueCrypt on a given distro there is loads of information with regard to using TrueCrypt on varying distros out there.

Comment: I don't believe this is a correct answer. TrueCrypt usually doesn't come with distributions, such as Ubuntu. What does come with distributions is dm-crypt (also known as cryptsetup or LUKS)

Comment: This answer needs to be revised as TrueCrypt does not come with linux systems, nor is available. The site now only gives instructions to migrate from TrueCrypt to Bitlocker.

Comment: @Pred Called out AES Crypt as another option since TrueCrypt has shut down.

Comment: VeraCrypt is a free disk encryption software brought to you by IDRIX (http://www.idrix.fr) and that is based on Small TrueCrypt.
It adds enhanced security to the algorithms used for system and partitions encryption making it immune to new developments in brute-force attacks.
For example, when the system partition is encrypted, TrueCrypt uses PBKDF2-RIPEMD160 with 1000 iterations whereas in VeraCrypt we use 327670. And for standard containers and other partitions, TrueCrypt uses at most 2000 iterations but VeraCrypt uses 655340 for RIPEMD160 and 500000 iterations for SHA-2 and Whirlpool.

Answer (score 13):

1. Most Linux distros give you full HD encryption option on installation (via LUKS).  If you have installed many major distros yourself in the past few years you should have seen this.
2. Some distros give you per-user directory encryption options on installation (via ecryptfs).  Ubuntu's UNR is an example.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to create an encrypted image that you mount using a local loopback.

This will allow you to 'open' an encrpyted image (which is kept on disk), modify its contents and upon unmounting, will be encrypted. Creates a nice easy way to transport encrypted files (just send the image).

A good ref is located [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/create-encrypted-loopback-filesystems-on-linux/).